# Post visibility based on user role

Tags: posts, user-roles, private

How can I make it so that new posts will be automatically private, except visible to other users which have the same user role as the post author?

Answer (score 0):

You can see this WordPress repository plugin. [Advanced Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/)

This Plugin's restricts role, users, author to post/page dashboard access etc.

I hope this plugin will help you.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that plugin, but it's not automatic and I couldn't get it to make posts disappear from the home page; once you clicked on the permalink it was indeed private, but the post still showed up in the list of posts.